# Add Picture to header of Word through vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-word

I am trying to insert a picture to the header of a word file through MS Access VBA. I cannot seem to get the code working:

```
Sub Insertpictoheader()
    Dim oHeader As Word.HeaderFooter
    Dim sh As Word.Shape, ils As Word.InlineShape

    Set oSec = ActiveDocument.Sections(1)
    Set oHeader = oSec.Headers(wdHeaderFooterFirstPage)
    oHeader.Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture "C:\Desktop\Logo.png"
End Sub
```

Nothing appears, I can get the image into the file but not the header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method below creates a table in header and adds an image. Just provide the path for the image.

Modify it if needed to fit your needs.

```
Public Sub UpdateHeader(oDoc As Word.Document)
    Dim oSec As Word.Section, rng As Range

    For Each oSec In oDoc.Sections
        Set rng = oSec.Headers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range
            With rng
                .Tables.Add Range:=rng, NumRows:=1, NumColumns:=1, DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitWindow
                With .Tables(1)
                    .Borders.InsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
                    .Borders.OutsideLineStyle = wdLineStyleNone
                    .Rows.SetLeftIndent LeftIndent:=-37, RulerStyle:=wdAdjustNone
                    .Cell(1, 1).Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture filename:="Your file path", LinkToFile:=False, SaveWithDocument:=True
                End With
            End With
    Next oSec
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Kostas, I am getting a problem when the compiller runs the code "Method or data member not found" for oDoc  and oSec. Here for oDoc For Each oSec In oDoc.Sections, here for oSec Set rng = oSec.Headers(Word.WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range

Comment: Okay I thought you were in Word. See updated answer (changed `Section` to `Word.Section`). You need to pass the `Word.Document` object as parameter to the method.

Comment: A hero amongst men you are Kostas!